# What's the purpose of the bitwise operations in this program?

Tags: javascript

Sorry about the vague question. Can anyone tell me what's the purpose/result of the bitwise operation  `bSet | bStyle << 1` in the following code? Is encoding needed for this particular code?

```
var aDOMFunc = [Element.prototype.removeAttribute,
  //....
  ];

  function setSomething(bStyle, sProp, sVal) {
    var bSet = Boolean(sVal), 
   fAction = aDOMFunc[bSet | bStyle << 1],
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you multiple bStyle by 2 and doing the bitwise or. I guess they have to encode it, so that it will give you the numbers in 0-3

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know the purpose without more context, but it looks like the intent is to build a bit value with the 'bset' bit added to the end. This could be for building a bitflag (a single value holding several settings), which the 'action' part of the variable name lends a smidgen of credence to.

Comment: I don't want to bore people with too many codes, but I get what you are saying